# Imagemagick distort values for GoPro Hero3+ Black lens correction

Tags: distortion, fisheye, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick to correct an image from the lens of a GoPro Hero3+ Black camera.  [I see here](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/lens/) that ImageMagick has both instructions and code parameters here for a GoPro Hero 3 but these settings are based on the Hero 3 do not match my 12 MP Hero3+ Black GoPro camera.

[I see from this web posting](https://im.snibgo.com/debarrel.htm) that there are some parameters for a Hero 3 Black but they do not have the desired results that I would expect. I assume the CMOS or the lens is different between the Hero3 Black and the Hero3+ Black cameras (or the parameters are just wrong).

Here is the original image I am trying to remove the fish-eye effect from:
[image]

Here is the output from using the wide angle parameters from the first link (left, first image) and from the Hero 3 Black website (right, second image)

```
magick GoPro.JPG -distort barrel "0.06335 -0.18432 0.13009" out2.png

magick GoPro.JPG -distort barrel "0.010 -0.32 0" out.png
```

[image][image]

Clearly the parameters are not correct.  Does anyone know the correct parameters for imagemagick distort barrel for a GoPro Hero3+ Black camera lens?  I am hoping to avoid having to calculate those parameters myself.

Comment: When you try the ImageMagick parameters from your first link, what results do you get?

Comment: @Saaru Lindestøkke - I have updated my post in response to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ImageMagick page on lens correction](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/lens/) has a section on [parameter sets](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/lens/#ready_made). There it links to [LensFun](https://github.com/lensfun/lensfun):

> When PTlens's database became encrypted, the authors of Hugin **tried to establish a free XML coded lens database as an alternative. This database is called LensFun** and can be downloaded. It comes with a complete programming interface, but **all you basically need is the information for your camera in the XML file**.

The GoPro Hero 3+ black is on the [supported camera list](https://lensfun.github.io/lenslist/2022/02/22/Lenslist-0.3.3/) of LensFun version 0.3.3, so that means the parameters should be available for that camera.

In the Github repository of LensFun you can actually inspect the [actioncams.xml file](https://github.com/lensfun/lensfun/blob/master/data/db/actioncams.xml#L132) and see the parameters for your GoPro:

```
<lens>
    <maker>GoPro</maker>
    <model>GoPro Hero3+ black &amp; compatibles</model>
    <model lang="en">fixed lens</model>
    <model lang="de">festes Objektiv</model>
    <mount>goProHero3+</mount>
    <cropfactor>5.42</cropfactor>
    <aspect-ratio>4:3</aspect-ratio>
    <calibration>
        <distortion model="ptlens" focal="15" a="0.01049" b="0.01663" c="-0.40901"/>
    </calibration>
</lens>
```

Plugging in those a, b and c values into ImageMagick gives a good result (compared to your other attempts):

```
magick .\gopro-image.jpg -distort barrel "0.01049 0.01663 -0.40901" out.png
```

[image: Distortion corrected image using magick and lensfun parameters for gopro hero 3+ black]